# Android Spinner style

Tags: android, styles, spinner

How can I make a spinner style like this [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)? I mean not in individual dialog. I will be glad for example.

I need something that:

[image: example]

Comment: you have full example in the link, what else you need ?

Comment: in this example I dont see, how can I make own layout for the spinner

Comment: There is a website: http://android-holo-colors.com/ which generates the required resources for you (including the spinner if you chose so). Once you add the resources to your project and set your theme to that generated theme, your spinners will look like the ones you posted, even on android versions < 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appearance of a Spinner varies by the android version the user is running.

This is how a Spinner looks like in android 2.x:

[image: Spinner UI in Android 2.x]

And this is how a Spinner looks like on a phone running Android 4.x:

[image: Spinner UI in Android 4.x]

The option menu in the second image is not a Spinner. It is a  [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) in the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) of an application.

Answer (score 0):

just add the spinner into your layout like this:

```
<Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinner"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt" />
```

Comment: in this example it looks like [this](http://savagelook.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/spinner.png)

Comment: i need something [that](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-iq8YXQBQjTo/TaXccBS9wZI/AAAAAAAAAVE/3NdspdF2eB4/s1600/I2.png)